# Android how, do I add instructions and screen captures to my install process

Tags: android, google-play

When one installs an android application they are typically greeted with an about this application screen. It talks of what the application does. Often there are images included.

This screen is presented before the permissions screen, during the install.

I would like to know how to create such a screen, and how to populate it.

Comment: please be more specific. Your title doesn't match what you are asking and your terminology is not descriptive enough to say what you are trying to do.

Comment: edited to reflect your comments.. I'm sure I still don't have the terms right, then I don't know the terms. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is on the market, these screenshots of one's application can be taken via the DDMS tool.

Comment: Oh.. so those things are not part of the APK, but rather something you set when you add to the market?